# Подскажите справочные ресурсы по Qt

Tags: qt, qt5

Изучаю `Qt` и хотелось бы иметь под рукой ресурс (вроде `cppreference.com`) с помощью которого можно было бы быстро находить и просматривать информацию по классам и функциям. Сам, к сожалению такого не нашел.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Прекрасная [документация](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/index.html) на официальном сайте проекта: [ссылки с классами](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/classes.html), [примеры](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtexamplesandtutorials.html), [справка по инструментам](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/topics-app-development.html) так же присутствует поиск, так же помимо всего этого, у данного проекта присутствует [форум](https://forum.qt.io/) *с [русской](https://forum.qt.io/category/27/russian) веткой*.

Comment: Да сдесь черт ногу сломает! Неужели нет чего более удобного, вроде того же `cppreference.com`?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch, Эм. Там все под рукой, есть ссылки на гайды с примерами, описание инструментов, просто референс с классами, поиск есть в конце концов) Что у вас не получается найти там?

Comment: @AndrejLevkovitch: У вас в папке с программой, если вы работаете под `Windows`, есть встроенная справка, которая работает оффлайн. помимо этого, вы всегда можете навести каретку на класс, нажать клавишу f1, и попадете в справку по классу.

Comment: @LLENN, Qt Assistant, он доступен через меню "Пуск"